# My File is not getting Saved on Herukou using Node js. But successfully getting saved on local File System

Tags: node.js, arrays, heroku

I am building an simple files uploader application in Nodejs. The files get successfully saved on the local storage in a directory 'upload' but now i have deployed my app to herukou. It is showing an error as[image: No such file or directory]. This is probably that there is no upload directory on herukou.

```
 'use strict';
 const express = require('express');
 const multer=require('multer');
 const uuid = require('uuid').v4;
 const app = express();
 let port=process.env.PORT || 8080;

 var storage= multer.diskStorage({
 destination: function(req,file,cb){
 cb(null,'upload')
 },
 filename: function(req,file,cb){
 cb(null,`${uuid()}-${file.originalname}`)
 }
 })

 const upload = multer({ storage : storage});

 app.use(express.static('Frontend'))
 app.post('/upload', upload.array('file'),function(req, res){
 res.send({
 status: 200,
 NumberofFileUploaded:req.files.length
 })
 })

app.listen(port, ()=> console.log(`Server Listening ${port}`))
```

The deployed link of my app is
https://fileuploader1997.herokuapp.com/

Anyone who can help me with this. Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Heroku filesystem is ephemeral, so the files that you try to save are not going to be stored. I would suggest using something like AWS S3 or similar in order to persist the uploaded files.

I'll leave the [link to the Heroku help](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) page where they explain this in detail.